# thumbnails для before after slider

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress, wp-plugin

Добрый  день,  столкнулся  с проблемой при работе с  before -after  слайдером.
При разработке сайта, клиент  захотел реализовать  thumbs для before - after slider, подскажите  как это реализовать? 
Или возможно  уже есть готовые  решения  для WP. Буду очень признателен.
Вот как должно выглядеть в конечном итоге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слайдер нужен динамический ? 
Так как если изображения будут статическими(тоесть слайдер будет создаватся вручную), можно выполнисть с использыванием Slider Revolution добавлением дополнительных слоев.